# performance issue for lambda usage

Tags: python, lambda

example code:

```
def var1(ll):
  s = sum(ll)
  l = len(ll)
  ave = float(s) / l
  s = 0
  for v in ll:
    s += (v - ave) * (v - ave)
  return math.sqrt(s/l)

def var2(ll):
  s = sum(ll)
  l = len(ll)
  ave = float(s) / l
  s = sum(map(lambda v: (v - ave) * (v - ave), ll))
  return math.sqrt(s/l)
```

for above two examples, there is an obvious difference between these two examples. The one use lambda cost much more time than another when the list (ll) is large enough.

from my view, the cause is clear. because lambda is anonymous function and the invocation of the function cost much time then a statement I think.

and a suggestion for using lambda is to replace some simple function. but from the experiment above, the performance is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "performance issue" you're seeing is not entirely related to your `lambda`.

```
  for v in ll:
    s += (v - ave) * (v - ave)
```

---

```
s = sum(map(lambda v: (v - ave) * (v - ave), ll))
```

---

These are **not** equivalent at all.

A closer equivalent to that your `map` expresses would be

```
temporary_list=[]
for v in ll:
    temporary_list.append( (v - ave) * (v - ave) )
s= sum(temporary_list)
```

Basically, you're building another list in memory when using `map`.

---

Ignoring this issue, note that using a `lambda` *will* still have some overhead, in the form of extra function calls.

If you want to keep your lambda, you could use `itertools.imap` to avoid creating the list.
Otherwise, `Vishnu Upadhyay`'s suggestion of a generator expression is probably the best solution, since it's more readable *and* has better performance

Comment: This is why you can't trust your intuition for optimizing.

Comment: in addition, there is some function call overhead from the lambda vs just evaluating the expression in the for loop

Comment: I didn't use `timeit`, but i use `cProfile` to profile the time consumption of these two implementation in my example code. even though the above code is not exactly equal, but in `cProfile` profiling result, the function created by lambda cost most time when ll is long enough. @Vishnu Upadhyay 's suggestion is a good replacement

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a `generator` expression.this wouldn't create an extra list in memory.

```
sum((v-ave)**2 for v in ll)
```

if we compare the time then

```
In [20]: %timeit sum(map(lambda v: (v - ave) * (v - ave), ll))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.7 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit sum((v-ave)**2 for v in ll)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.8 ms per loop
```

in python3:-

```
In [9]:  %timeit sum((v-ave)**2 for v in ll)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.7 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit sum(map(lambda v: (v - ave) * (v - ave), ll))
10 loops, best of 3: 33.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Did you do the timing test with Python 3?

Comment: yes. using the generator expression has the better performance because it doesn't have a function call overhead.

Comment: @gg_fei check the updated code for python3. generators are faster because here its are `expression` while in `map` & `lambda` make it little slower then generator.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay Yes. I agree about `expression` is much faster than `map` & `lambda`. That's also what I want to express, `map` & `lambda` slower than the `expression`. Additionally, I want to say we should't use lambda in most cases. Each time call to `lambda` anonymous function have function call overhead.

Comment: @gg_fei i am just trying to tell it by showing output, please  mark correct if you get it as right answer. :-)